# How to inject all instances registered of the generic class Sample<T> in DotNet Core?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have 3 instances registered of the class Metadata. I don't have generic interface.

```
services.AddSingleton(new Metadata<Heartbeat1Job>(Constants.Heartbeat1JobName));
services.AddSingleton(new Metadata<Heartbeat2Job>(Constants.Heartbeat2JobName));
services.AddSingleton(new Metadata<Heartbeat3Job>(Constants.Heartbeat3JobName));
```

Now, I want to inject the list of all generic type instances of the class Metadata registered into the Controller...

```
// This may be the invalid syntax and it's 
// just for the demonstration purpose...

private readonly IEnumerable<Metadata<T>> metadatas;

public TestController(IEnumerable<Metadata<T>> metadatas)
{
    this.metadatas = metadatas;
}
```

How can I achieve this please?

Answer (score 3):

You can create an interface exposing the methods you are interested in from the Metadata class. Lets name it IMetadata

```
public interface IMetadata
{
    ....
}
```

Your Metadata class will require some refactoring. Your Constants (based on your example) does not need to be passed as a parameter in the constructor but you can access it in the class as it is a static.

```
public class Metadata<T>: IMetadata
{
    ....
}
```

Then

```
 services.AddSingleton<IMetadata, Metadata<Heartbeat1Job>>();
 services.AddSingleton<IMetadata, Metadata<Heartbeat2Job>>();
 services.AddSingleton<IMetadata, Metadata<Heartbeat3Job>>();
```

Finally in the class using the injected `IMetadata` you can do

```
private readonly IEnumerable<IMetadata> metadatas;

public TestController(IEnumerable<IMetadata> metadatas)
{
    this.metadatas = metadatas;
}
```

In the way I described above you register a number of implementations on your IMetadata interface. When resolving IMetadata you will get an IEnumerable of the all the implementations you registered in the DI container.